# Display unread and amount of mails in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I could only find that you can show unread or read mails, but is it possible to show the amount of mails in a folder, ie 7/10, meaning 7 unread and 10 mails all together in that folder. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> but is it possible to show the amount of mails in a folder, ie 7/10,
> meaning 7 unread and 10 mails all together in that folder.

Yes, you can do this. In Outlook (2016 /365) the total number of emails in a folder, together with the number of unread emails in the same folder shows in a status line, bottom left of Outlook, under the Email, People and Calendar icons.

The statistics show for each folder, that is, for all folders in Outlook. You can also customize this statistic if you wish by right clicking on it. You can show other statistics as well as read / unread.

Here are two screen shots showing the possibilities.

[image: Outlook unread status]

.

[image: Outlook statistics customization]

Comment: Might be worth adding a comment on the ability to customise that panel, to show/hide some statistics. If you right-click in that area, you can turn off `Items in view` (items) and `Unread items in view` (unread)

Comment: You're right, thank you for that, but is it possible to have that view for each folder? Right now I have to click on a folder so I can see the values. Is it possible to see those numbers in all the folders all the time?

Comment: @MaxMustemal you can only show total or unread, not both, on the name of the folder.

Comment: I have made changes in my answer to reflect the customization possibilities.

Comment: Is it possible to see those numbers in all the folders all the time?     ....... Not all these values all the time. The customization was done in the Status line and that is where the information resides.

Comment: Agree with John and spikey_richie. Just to supplement spikey_richie's comment "you can only show total or unread, not both, on the name of the folder", you can right click the folder>Properties…>under General tab, and choose "Show number of unread items" or "Show total number of items".

Comment: Has your problem been solved? If so, please remember to mark the helpful reply as the answer so that users with similar questions can get reference. Warm marks.